# Is best practice for new Google Analytics project, to duplicate the data?

Tags: google-analytics

I haven't been involved with GA for about 7 years. At that time I recall a suggestion that as soon as you create a new project, you somehow "duplicated" it (created views on it?) and then you went and did all your analytics reports on the duplicated/filtered version of the project. You could set up several such filters/views/versions. The idea was to prevent you accidentally irretrievably destroying your source data. Does anyone remember this practice and is this still the way to go now? Can someone point me to an article that articulates this a bit better?

Comment: Data is collected at property level, so views do not "duplicate" data (they just display the same data filtered by different criteria). Since view filters are destructive it is still recommended to keep an unfiltered view (just in case you accidentally destroyed too much). Since this is not code related I'm not sure this is on-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/